# About a function continuous on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Given that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(f(x))=x$ prove that $f(x)=x$. 
I've been thinking about this one for ages, but I can't figure out even where to begin. Give me some hints, please?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: An injective continuous function is monotonic. If $f(x_0) \ne x_0$ for some $x_0 \in (0,1)$, then either $f(x_0) > x_0$ or $f(x_0) < x_0$. Show that both cases are impossible for a monotonic function.

Comment: Why do you assume injectivity?

Comment: $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=f(f(x))=f(f(y))=y$.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a different problem. (Now of course I understand why you simply started talking about injectivity instead of explaning why.) I first thought that $x$ was just a fixed point of $f \circ f$. I gave it a thought for about 10 seconds so I was still confused. Perfectly good answer. +1

Comment: Thanks. Since the downvoter removed his/her downvote, I deleted my previous comment.